# ASP.NET MVC Routes being ignored.

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a route configured to capture all urls matching /careers/*. The code used is as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute("CareersRedirect", "careers/{*path}", new { controller = RedirectPermanent", action = "Index", RedirectPermanentController = "Home", redirectPermanentAction = "Index" }, namespaces);
```

As far as I can see I don't think there's an issue with the code above, however if I browse to /careers/anything the route is ignored and I get a 404.

I only thing I can see different is that the careers directory is actually configured as an application in IIS. Would this have anything to do with the route being ignored?

Thanks, David

Comment: Can you post the whole route definition? Probably a more general route is added earlier than this one

Comment: Try debugging your routes with something like Glimpse http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek5DebuggingASPNETMVCApplicationsWithGlimpse.aspx

Comment: You need to check the order in wich the routes are in your code, that is very important, please, put all the routes code here

Comment: Well, there doesn't appear to be an issue with ***this*** route, but as others have pointed out if you have a matching route before this one it will never be reached. Please post the rest of your route config, including startup, attribute routes, and areas.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for taking the time to look at this. There's literally 100s of routes in the project so not much point posting them all. I was mostly wondering if having a sub folder set as an application in iis would have anything to do with a route being ignored?

Comment: Likely, yes. Since IIS is setup to treat the directory as a full-fledged application of its own, it never touches your root application, but proxies the request directly to the sub-application.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your message. Do you have any idea how I would get round this as I'm totally stuck.

Comment: IIS gets your request before MVC and it is going to prefer the application defined on the website.  I am not sure there is any way around this if you can't change the IIS app or your folder name.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone has the same issue I can confirm that having a sub folder set as an application in IIS will ignore any routing settings you have in the parent site.

Answer (score 0):

Just move your rout to first line of RegisterRoutes method.
I had a similar problem, but unexpectedly moving the rout to first line resolved my problem.

Comment: Tried that mate. If you set up a sub folder application in IIS then try setting up a route to intercept that folder in the parent application it is ignored.